# how to get machine name of taxonomy term in code?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

How to get machine name of taxonomy term in code having taxonomy term ID in Drupal 7?

I tried taxonomy_term_load() , but it doesn't return machine name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pathauto's` [pathauto_cleanstring](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_cleanstring/7)() function to clean up the string of your taxonomy term.

Comment: Your solution return me Vocabulary Object ` $voc `.
But I need to get " taxonomy term " machine-name !

Comment: No Mr. Muhammad, your code return Vocabulary machine-name.
I need machine name of taxonomy term witch is in a vocabulary !

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such a thing called `taxonomy machine name`. Could you give me an example of what you need?!

Comment: Ok, I set Pattern Aliases (/admin/config/search/path/patterns) for taxonomy as << resource/[term:name] >> and the output link is << resource/position-statements >>. 
So I need to create an link witch will look like this <<  resource/position-statements >>. This is my problem, where is taken this << position-statements >> while title is << POSITION STATEMENTS >>.
Hope this make sense.

Comment: It's `pathauto` module that handles this.

Comment: Ok. How can I reproduce generated path by pathauto, having ID and name of taxonomy term?

Answer (score 3):

Natively taxonomy term doesn't support machine name such as vocabulary.
I have just developped a module to support a such feature.
It alters taxonomy term properties by addind a new field named "machine_name" which can be typed or automatically generated using the term name.

https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_machine_name

Hope it helps you or someone else.

BR

Comment: Not bad, should get rid of some extra left joins.

Comment: It should ! I've added too support for Token, Views and Migrate.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this path is generated by Drupal core module "path" and I solved in following way.

```
$out_alias = drupal_lookup_path('alias', 'taxonomy/term/3');
```

The second option could be:

```
$out_alias = url('taxonomy/term/3');
```

Thanks for your time.